# Creating a decent Tripwire policy

Tags: linux, security, tripwire

I installed Tripwire on a few servers many years ago, and started out with the default policy file supplied by the distro. There were a huge number of references to files that didn't exist (because the relevant packages weren't installed), a lot of files that I thought should be included but weren't; and no doubt a lot of files that should have been included which I didn't think about. In summary, it was a painful experience, and I don't think I got the best out of it.

It's that time of the decade when shiny new servers turn up in the mail, and I intend to do things better this time. So, I did this:

```
Strict = $(IgnoreNone) -ar;

!/home;
!/proc;
!/run;
!/sys;
!/tmp;

/                                               -> $(Strict) (recurse=true);
/boot                                           -> $(Strict) (recurse=true);
/boot/efi                                       -> $(Strict) (recurse=true);
/dev                                            -> $(Device) (recurse=true);
/dev/hugepages                                  -> $(Device) (recurse=true);
/dev/mqueue                                     -> $(Device) (recurse=true);
/dev/pts                                        -> $(Device) (recurse=true);
/dev/shm                                        -> $(Device) (recurse=true);
/var/lib/tripwire/$(HOSTNAME).twd               -> $(Dynamic) -i;
/var/lib/tripwire/report                        -> $(Dynamic) (recurse=0);
/var/log                                        -> $(Growing) -i (recurse=true);
```

My expectation is that over the next few days/weeks, I'll probably end up with plenty of alerts for completely innocent changes, but I can then review those and modify the policy file as appropriate. Fairly soon I should end up with a sensible policy.

Am I completely insane, or is this a reasonable place to start?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used tripwire, but this looks OK.  I don't know what the policy for `$(Device)` is, but it's worth noting that `/dev` is fairly dynamic.  Device nodes are created and removed whenever you log with a pty (e.g. ssh), or mount a usb or cdrom or whatever, or create a loopback device, or create a zvol if you're using zfs, etc etc etc.

Comment: /var/lib, /var/cache, /var/tmp, /var/mail, and /var/spool can all change frequently too, and many other directories under /var.   So you probably don't want them $(Strict).